# infrastructureUpdate type OU called Infrastructure in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, organizational-unit

A new OU called infrastructure with the type infrastructureUpdate has appeared in my Active Directory.

[image: what I am seeing]

It has just appeared. I have been going through the setup recently and the last major thing I have probably done is configure WSUS. Can someone explain what this is and if I should be worried? My first thought was a Phantom OU but the fact it does not have the correct icon worries me.
I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to do with WSUS.  You're probably seeing this due to you have View > Advanced selected.

InfrastructureUpdate object holds the infrastructure master for the domain.

Infrastructure-Update class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx